# Finding all storage devices attached to a Linux machine

Tags: linux, storage

I have a need to find all of the writable storage devices attached to a given machine, whether or not they are mounted.

The dopey way to do this would be to try every entry in `/dev` that corresponds to a writable devices (hd* and sd*).

Is there a better solution, or should I stick with this one?

Comment: reasking an old [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/200960/4418)

Comment: Perhaps you want to use udisks?

Comment: I do not *merely* want to find what hard disks are on a system - I am looking for *all* storage devices

Comment: I think we all assumed hard disks and similar. Do you actually mean something else? Like, should it include tape drives, printers, etc.?

Comment: @derobert - yes, hence the title of "all storage devices" :)

Answer (score 74, accepted):

If one is interested only in **block** storage devices, one can use `lsblk` from widely-available util-linux package:

```
$ lsblk -o KNAME,TYPE,SIZE,MODEL
KNAME TYPE   SIZE MODEL
sda   disk 149.1G TOSHIBA MK1637GS
sda1  part  23.3G 
sda2  part    28G 
sda3  part  93.6G 
sda4  part   4.3G 
sr0   rom   1024M CD/DVDW TS-L632M
```

It lends itself well to scripting with many other columns available.

Comment: This is NOT block storage "devices", it is only list of partitions. And you can't use this command to get devices which does not have any partition or not formatted.

Comment: @YoushaAleayoub sda and sr0 are it (devices). `lsblk` lists _only_ block devices if you run it with `--nodeps` program switch.

Answer (score 19):

You could trawl through the output of `lshw` and extract details about devices in the `disk` or `tape` class (and maybe others - `storage` class gives you details on storage controllers, scsi, sata, sas, etc).

e.g.

```
lshw -class disk -class tape
```

The `-short` option gives a nice compact summary.  e.g. on my home zfsonlinux server/workstation/experiment-box (no tape devices unfortunately):

```
# lshw -class tape -class disk -class storage -short
H/W path              Device      Class       Description
=========================================================
/0/100/4/0                        storage     JMB362 SATA Controller
/0/100/5/0            scsi10      storage     JMB362 SATA Controller
/0/100/5/0/0.0.0      /dev/sdc    disk        120GB Patriot Wildfire
/0/100/b/0            scsi1       storage     SAS2008 PCI-Express Fusion-MPT SAS-2 [Falcon]
/0/100/b/0/0.0.0      /dev/sdd    disk        1TB WDC WD10EARS-00Y
/0/100/b/0/0.1.0      /dev/sde    disk        1TB WDC WD10EACS-00Z
/0/100/b/0/0.2.0      /dev/sdf    disk        1TB WDC WD10EACS-00Z
/0/100/b/0/0.3.0      /dev/sdg    disk        1TB ST31000528AS
/0/100/b/0/0.4.0      /dev/sdh    disk        1TB ST31000528AS
/0/100/b/0/0.5.0      /dev/sdi    disk        1TB ST31000528AS
/0/100/b/0/0.6.0      /dev/sdj    disk        1TB ST31000528AS
/0/100/11             scsi2       storage     SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 SATA Controller [AHCI mode]
/0/100/11/0           /dev/sda    disk        128GB Patriot Torqx 2
/0/100/11/1           /dev/sdb    disk        1TB ST31000528AS
/0/1                  scsi11      storage     
/0/1/0.0.0            /dev/sdk    disk        1967MB SCSI Disk
/0/1/0.0.1            /dev/sdl    disk        SCSI Disk
/0/1/0.0.2            /dev/sdm    disk        SCSI Disk
/0/1/0.0.3            /dev/sdn    disk        SCSI Disk
/0/2                  scsi66      storage     
/0/2/0.0.0            /dev/sdo    disk        SCSI Disk
/0/3                  scsi67      storage     
/0/3/0.0.0            /dev/sdp    disk        4057MB SCSI Disk
```

The /0/1 devices are actually a USB card-reader (there's a 2GB SD card plugged in to one of the slots), and the /0/2 device is my android phone plugged in for charging only.  The 0/3 device is a 4GB USB flash drive.

`lshw` can produce plain text, html, xml, and json output.  It can also dump hardware details into an sqlite database format.

It is packaged for debian and most other distros.  The home page and source is at http://ezix.org/project/wiki/HardwareLiSter

Comment: This command is really impressive! Helped a ton! Sadly, it doesn't show which drives are connected through SAS expanders. Is there a way to see that as well? I know it's possible when you get the `X:X:X:X` syntax.

Answer (score 8):

You can use `lsblk` to list all block devices, along with whether or not each device is read only.

You can then use `grep` and `awk` to print the names of block devices that are not read only:

```
lsblk -d -n -oNAME,RO | grep '0$' | awk {'print $1'}
```

Comment: this is a great expansion on the previous [answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/94209/6388)

Comment: You can use awk to do grep's work as well: `awk '/0$/ {print $1}'`

Answer (score 7):

Please, try this command

```
ls -l /dev /dev/mapper |grep '^b'
```

It will list you all block devices in your system

Answer (score 5):

`lsblk` will list all block storage devices.

`fdisk -l` will list all of the partitions on all devices that are listed in `/proc/partitions`

`lshw -short` will give you information about all of the hardware (except perhaps firewire) on the system.

Comment: "lsblk will list all block storage devices." NO. This lists all partitions...

Answer (score 4):

You can use [hwinfo](https://github.com/openSUSE/hwinfo) to list all disks ([documentation](http://www.linuxintro.org/wiki/Hwinfo)).

`hwinfo --block --short` gives an overview:

```
disk:
  /dev/sdb             WDC WD3200AAKS-7
  /dev/sda             SAMSUNG HD103UJ
partition:
  /dev/sdb1            Partition
  /dev/sdb2            Partition
  /dev/sda1            Partition
cdrom:
  /dev/sr1             TSSTcorp DVD+-RW TS-H653B
  /dev/sr0             HL-DT-ST DVD-ROM GDRH20N
```

`hwinfo --disk` gives more details for each disk.

FYI: on some Linux distributions such as Ubuntus 14.04 and higher, [hwinfo isn't present in the official repository](https://askubuntu.com/q/662971/44876).

Answer (score 3):

If, as per your response to derobert, you're looking for something that lists tape drives and *printers*, you may be interested in `lsdev`, `lsusb` and `lspci`.

Comment: Of course, that'll fail to find network-attached storage :-(

Comment: Then `fdisk -l`

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following command :

```
file /dev/disk/by-id/* | awk -F'/' 'NR>1{print "\047/dev/"$NF}' | sort | uniq
```

Comment: what does it do and how does that compare to listing block and tape device classes with lshw?

Answer (score 0):

I have found that `fdisk` and `lsblk` are not available in the virtual terminal for the Debian installer. In this case I use `blkid`, which gets the UUID for block storage devices.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to RAID devices then you would not be able to get correct result using hdparm smartctl etc because these kind of tools look for /dev which is OS level if you would like to know on Hardware Level then you need to have tool like megacli i used to debug with megacli

```
    [root@ns3539186 ~]# /opt/megaraid/megacli -LDPDInfo -aAll |grep "Virtual Disks\|RAID Level\|State"
Number of Virtual Disks: 2
RAID Level          : Primary-1, Secondary-0, RAID Level Qualifier-0
State               : Optimal
Foreign State: None
Media Type: Solid State Device
Foreign State: None
Media Type: Solid State Device
RAID Level          : Primary-1, Secondary-0, RAID Level Qualifier-0
State               : Optimal
Foreign State: None
Foreign State: None
```

To get serial number of the disk

```
[root@ns3539186 ~]# /opt/megaraid/megacli -PDList -aAll | egrep 'Slot\ Number|Device\ Id|Inquiry\ Data|Raw|Firmware\ state' | sed 's/Slot/\nSlot/g' |grep "Da                    ta\|Slot\|Raw"
Slot Number: 0
Raw Size: 447.130 GB [0x37e436b0 Sectors]
Inquiry Data: PHYS733402Z0480BGN  INTEL SSDSC2KB480G7                     SCV10100
Slot Number: 1
Raw Size: 447.130 GB [0x37e436b0 Sectors]
Inquiry Data: PHYS733402YV480BGN  INTEL SSDSC2KB480G7                     SCV10100
Slot Number: 2
Raw Size: 3.638 TB [0x1d1c0beb0 Sectors]
Inquiry Data: K3GJTYMB            HGST HUS726040ALA610                    A5GNT920
Slot Number: 3
Raw Size: 3.638 TB [0x1d1c0beb0 Sectors]
Inquiry Data: K3GHW57B            HGST HUS726040ALA610                    A5GNT920
```

In above output Inquiry Data contains Serial number

Answer (score -1):

Here are the couple of commands I used to find local and shared storage.

For local storage

```
lsblk | grep -v '^loop'
```

For shared storage

```
findmnt -D | grep -v '^tmpfs' | grep -v '^/'

OR

df -kh | grep -v '^tmpfs' | grep -v '^/'
```

Comment: Why resuggest the same tools already suggested (and accepted) 6+ years ago?

Comment: Because the OS changed and now you get a lot of `loop` and `tmpfs` partition. So its better to clean the output using grep as above.

Answer (score -1):

List all block devices:

```
find / -type b 2>/dev/null
```

Comment: sorry, but that also finds virtual things like docker containers in `/var` and items in `/run`

Answer (score -4):

This will list all your disks and mounted drives:

```
$ df -h
```

Comment: Actually, that lists filesystems…